# Custom button is not showing in the VS code editor title menu bar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In an extension I want to add a button to display in the VS code editor title menu bar when it opens a synapse XML document.In order to that, I added the following command in commands of package.json file,

```
{
    "command": "webview.show",
    "title": "Show Diagram",
    "category": "Webview",
    "icon": {
        "light": "./resources/images/icons/design-view.svg",
        "dark": "./resources/images/icons/design-view-inverse.svg"
    }
}
```

and in the package.json file I added the following editor/title,

```
"menus": {
    "editor/title": [
        {
            "when": "resourceLangId == SynapseXml",
            "command": "webview.show",
            "group": "navigation"
        }
    ],
}
```

But when I run the extension and opens a synapse XML document, it will not showing the button in the editor title menu bar.

Further I followed following documentation also,
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus

How can I display the button in VS code editor title menu bar?

Comment: Are you sure the `resourceLangId` is correct? Have you tried without any `when` condition as a sanity check?

Comment: yes.`resourceLangId` is correct.I tried with different `when` conditions also.But it doesn't works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure your extension is active? What are your `activationEvents`? Maybe try putting `"*"` in there?

Comment: extension is active & I tried with putting `"*"` to `activationEvents` also.but doesn't works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I added your command and menu entry to an extension I'm making and the button appears where it should (all be it without an image in my screenshot as I don't have the icon). In my screenshot it is the empty space on the left of the ying-yang button - the tooltip is visible though on mouse over. I just removed the "where" test so I would guess that resourceLangId is not what you think it is or maybe the icons path is wrong so it looks like it isn't there as in my screenshot

[image]

Comment: In my case, it needs the `when` condition to display the button only when the `SynapseXml` file has been opened.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having the same issue:

In my case, using the correct context name field (`editorLangId`) to match the language ID in the `when` clause of the command fixed the issue.

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#available-contexts

```json
"menus": {
    "editor/title": [
        {
            "when": "editorLangId == SynapseXml",
            "command": "webview.show",
            "group": "navigation"
        }
    ]
}
```